# cannot view the seaborn factorplot

Tags: python

I am trying to create a factorplot to study the relation between port embarked and the survival rate on the titanic dataset.But on running this code snippet,the plot is not showing up in the jupyter notebook.

```
 import seaborn as sns
 import pandas as pd
 titanic_df=pd.read_csv('titanic_data.csv')
 g=sns.factorplot(x="Embarked",y="Survived",data=titanic_df)
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: no error messsages,nothing showing up

Comment: Have you added %matplotlib inline ?

Comment: yes I have,no effect

Answer (score 0):

You can update the seaborn to seaborn-0.12.2 with the below command:

- pip install -U seaborn

In the latest command factorplot is replaced with catplot. So replace

```
g=sns.factorplot(x="Embarked",y="Survived",data=titanic_df)
```

with

```
g=sns.catplot(x="Embarked",y="Survived",data=titanic_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the below error,

```
AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'factorplot'
```

To solve the above error, Firstly You have to update your seaborn with the help of the below commands

```
pip install -U seabor
```

> It will update as version v0.12.2.

In that version, factorplot is replaced with catplot.

Then simplely Run

```
g=sns.catplot(x="Embarked",y="Survived",data=titanic_df)
```